# Mysteriously Slow Wordpress Dashboard - No Slow Queries

Tags: dashboard

This is my first time posting to this forum for help in the last 4 years of using WP.

Getting to the point - I am experiencing an initial lag when I update a post in the wordpress dashboard.

I checked for slow queries using query monitor but there are non. The longest query takes about .0063 seconds. It is related to options with autoload on. I even tried to create an index for the options but it didn't help.

here is screenshot - https://pasteboard.co/IiEPROz.jpg

Now the query monitor shows the post is updated in 1.23 second but in real use it takes about 15-20 seconds to update the post.

Now I opened the Google developer tools to see what was happening - and it shows that the post.php takes around 5-6 seconds initially to respond which is long.

Screenshot - https://pasteboard.co/IiEP8NM.jpg.

So I have been scratching my head for almost 7 days now to figure out the reason why there is an initial lag but unable to do it.

I am running the site on a VPS with 4 GB ram and 2 Cores + ssd. Nginx+Php 7 + memcache and Fast CGI.

Also, have CF cdn and have disabled dashboard in page rules.

Any expert has some guidance on how to find out the reason for the initial delay - can please share with me.

Will be really happy to get some help on this.

Comment: '*initial lag*' means change the hosting. Try to  `traceroute` to get where it restains.

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange :) We love to help. Unfortunately by only stating facts or asking for Any help? you are asking a too broad question. Debugging always needs to be done by you, as that can't be achieved from a far without back-and-forth clarification in comments. But WPSE is no forum, it's a Q&A, providing canonical answers to narrowly scoped and reproducible questions.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find where does the code slow down, try:

- Deactivating  all plugins and then check speed. If this works,
  re-activate them individually( one-by-one ) to find the problematic
  plugin(s).
- Switching theme then check speed.
- Transfer the theme and plugins to a new WordPress that installed from
  scratch, then check.

Then write the results.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have added the issue details in one of the answer below. -yes this is an excellent approach to debugging WP issues which are mostly either theme or plugin related - in our case it was Two factor authentication which was causing the delay. Site is over 5 years old ahd has many plugins and it is sometimes painful to deactivate all and trouble shoot on a live site.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Rimarx has already suggested, another possible cause (among many) is with the Updates API making external calls which eventually timeout, you can try setting this in your `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL', true);
define('WP_ACCESSIBLE_HOSTS', '*.wordpress.org');
```

If this works, it is possibly a plugin or theme checking for updates on a slow update server, or where the connection to it is timing out. Again, just one thing to check / eliminate. (If it does make a difference, you would have to narrow down which plugin / theme is causing the issue and go from there.)

Comment: Thanks For the suggestion - actually did some more debugging and found the major culprit as two factor authentication plugin which was causing about 1 second delay on post edits also there is an issue with a plugin used by the theme found it in the wp debug log  plugins/td-cloud-library/includes/tdb_functions.php on line 131 not sure how to debug it. I am checking with the author of theme newspaper for a fix as it is an essential plugin to use with this theme.